# What happens when Exception occurs in a method in Multicast Delegate

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to understand whats the best way to handle exceptions in Multicast delegates ?

My question is, what happens if a method throw exception in Multicast delegate execution ? Will it stop ? Continue ? How to handle ? A small program with explanation will be really helpful if somebody can share please.... thank you....

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The exception will be propagated immediately, and any "later" actions in the delegate's invocation list will *not* get executed. If you want to make sure you execute *all* the delegates - perhaps aggregating all the exceptions together, for example - you'd need to call [`Delegate.GetInvocationList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.getinvocationlist.aspx), cast each of those delegates to the same type as the original, and invoke them one by one, catching the exceptions as they were thrown.

Here's some sample code which does this - it would be nice to do this in a more generic way, ideally building a new delegate which (when executed) would execute all of the constituent delegates and aggregate the exceptions... but this is a start.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Action x = null;
        x += () => Console.WriteLine("First");
        x += () => { throw new Exception("Bang 1"); };
        x += () => { throw new Exception("Bang 2"); };
        x += () => Console.WriteLine("Second");

        try
        {
            ExecuteAll<Action>(x, action => action());
        }
        catch (AggregateException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
    }

    public static void ExecuteAll<T>(Delegate multi, Action<T> invoker)
    {
        List<Exception> exceptions = new List<Exception>();
        foreach (var single in multi.GetInvocationList())
        {
            try
            {
                invoker((T)(object)single);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                exceptions.Add(e);
            }
        }
        if (exceptions.Count > 0)
        {
            throw new AggregateException(exceptions);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Jon, thank you, thats exactly what I was trying to understand. Well. One thing I dint get in your statement is, "Cast each of those delegates to the same type" means, you are talking about multiple individual delegates ? uhmm sorry couldn't understand it as I am new to this.... I know it could be silly....

Comment: @Divine: Each of the elements of the array returned by `GetInvocationList` is the same type as the original delegate - but one with only a single action. It's fine to be confused by this - the lack of good terminology doesn't help :(

Comment: Here I think I am little confused with the term "type"...type refers to return type you talking about ? or signature ? As I knew void is return type for multicast delegates....and fantastic program for me to understand....I will use this in my VS and understand it now ....:) thank you so much Jon, I appreciate it... :)

Comment: @Divine: The type of the delegate you call it on, e.g. `Action`, `EventHandler` etc. In some ways you may not want to think too much about my code to start with - it's worse than I'd like it to be, partly because C# won't let me add a constraint to force `T` to be a delegate type.

Comment: Uhmmm GREAT thanks a lot Jon :) I got it and will dive more into these stuffs....Your code looks helpful to me to start with.... As you suggest, I will understand it more for going into generics....but generics is again pretty new for me :P :) Thank you so much for helping me understand this and your time and kind replies :) Cheers

Answer (score 0):

It will work like any other exception and it will work the same as a not-multicast delegate: The exception propagates up the stack.